# Tkinter main window becomes unresponsive after message box

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

I have problem with Tkinter. After messagebox I can't edit Entry in main window. Below simply code with this problem. Can you help me?

```
from tkinter import messagebox, Entry, Tk


def pop_error():
    messagebox.showerror(message="Error")


win = Tk()
entry = Entry(win)
entry.grid()
pop_error()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Not sure about what you mean by "edit Entry"...

Comment: User can't enter text in the Entry widget

Comment: tell me if the answer below does the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Force the `Entry` to focus after closing the `messagebox`

```
from tkinter import messagebox, Entry, Tk

def pop_error():
    messagebox.showerror(message="Error")

win = Tk()
entry = Entry(win)
entry.grid()
pop_error()
entry.focus_force()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! Do you know why this messagebox block main window? For me it is strange.